# Herramienta para guardar script en sql mientras desarrollas para pasar a producción

Tags: sql-server

Existe alguna herramienta para guardar los scripts de los stores proc (no solamete stors, pueden ser funciones, tablas, trigers etc)
que vas creando en desarrollo. Para que al final cuando terminas de desarrollar puedas pasar a producción. sin la necesidad de estar buscando
los script o estar guardando en otro archivo aparte ( Actualmente estoy trabajando de esta manera pero a veces se me olvida). Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server 2008 R2 puedes usar el mismo programa para generar dichos scripts cuando los necesites, ya sea todos de un golpe o individualmente.

**Individual**
Buscas el objeto en el explorador de objetos, click derecho y generas el script que estés necesitando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Colectiva**
Buscas la base de datos de la cual deseas obtener los scripts que necesites, **Tasks**, **Generate scripts...**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ella se abrirá un asistente que te ayudará a seleccionar los objetos que necesites, tanto tablas, store procedures o vistas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que selecciones los objetos que necesites en la siguiente pantalla seleccionas como los quieres almacenar, en un script guardandolo o en un script en pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Una de las cosas destacables que tiene utilizar esta opción, es que en caso de necesitar generar un script tanto con estructura y data (o solamente una de ellas) debes especificar en las opciones **Avanzadas**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero estas opciones te ayuden a poder guardar tus scripts, ya con ello es solamente organizar tu repo. Saludos.